# Google Cloud API credentials disappeared

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using Google Cloud's API to integrate with Laravel/Socialite. I created an account and within the account I created a new Project.

Within the project, I created new credentials `OauthClientID` and was successful using them in my application. I logged back in today and I still see my project but when I click into the `credentials` sidebar link my credentials are gone. I didn't accidentally delete them nor did I change anything after creating them. Why would they be gone from my Account -> Project?

[image]

Comment: 1) Are the credentials still working? If yes, you have selected the wrong project. 2) Did you have a Billing problem? 3) Google Cloud **Audit Logs** record activity such as creating and deleting resources. If this occurred in the last 30 days, there will be a log entry of when and by who deleted the credentials. 4) For problems like yours, you need Google Cloud support.

Comment: Is the same project?

Comment: Yes I only have one project existing so no other projects are there. The credentials do still work in my laravel app though so it's odd.

Comment: The app that is using the credentials will have an OAuth Client secrets file. Look in that file and double-check the **project_id** value. Confirm you are using the correct project. Beyond that, you will need Google Cloud support.

Comment: I will do that, thank you @JohnHanley